# Session token keeps changing on each message sending using websocket

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, websocket, multi-tenant

I'm using multi tenancy in my application with this package:
https://tenancyforlaravel.com/

Here everything is working good as per requirements. But my application is having chat functionality for having messages using websocket.

So, when I run `npm run watch` and `node public/js/socket-io-server.js` to send messages between clients, that means websocket is established.
So when this websocket is established, my application is kept logging out on each page refresh.

**Example:**

If I'm running my application without the package above mentioned, and if I established websocket to send messages, it is working good as I'm checking `$request->session()->token()` having same value on each message and doesn't go logout if I refresh.

But if I use the package for multi tenancy as mentioned above, and if I established websocket to send messages, the page is being logged out because this package changing the value of `$request->session()->token()`. I couldn't identify from where this is being happened.

If I closed the websocket, then it works good and pages are not being logged out. This happens only if **I use package (https://tenancyforlaravel.com/)** and if **I established websocket**.

How can I avoid that the token changes or that it causes my application to log out?

Comment: Maybe work with cookies?